# sticky topbar (css)

Tags: feature-request, top-bar, information-display

There are times when I "zap" through posts on PPCG: I come back after a few hours absence, see a couple of votes and notifications. So I pick one, after reviewing it, I have to scroll all the way to the top of the page to get to the next one, and so on.

Ok, it´s "only" a click followed by `Strg`+`PgUp` or a drag on the scroll bar; but it´s getting on my nerves when I have to do that a dozen times in a row.

Can I have a sticky `topbar` please!

Comment: You can open PPCG (or some else SE site) in a new tab to quickly check notifications.

Comment: Add a user style of something like `.topbar { position: fixed; top: 0; z-index: 9999; ) .container { margin-top: 33px; }` and you're done.

Comment: @Cai: Excellent! Where can I do that?

Comment: In your browser, how depends on your browser. Just google "[your browser] user style"

Comment: @Cai just did that, thanks. Maybe add that comment as answer to the other thread. Oh there´s already something. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Titus [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](http://stackapps.com/q/6091/26088) does this and a whole lot more if you're interested! :) (I'm one of the authors of it :)